# OpenAPI ref pointing to same object not working

Tags: aws-api-gateway, openapi

```
definitions:   
   TestObject2:
        type: object
        properties:
          key1:
            type: string
   TestObject:
        type: object
        properties:
          name:
            type: string
          city:
            type: string
          coordinates:
            $ref: '#/definitions/TestObject2'
          directions:
            $ref: '#/definitions/TestObject2'
```

If I remove the reference for one of them to TestObject2, then it works. But if I add same reference to a different property, I don't see the model getting created on api gateway "Models"
In the logs I see this:

```
paths:
          '/my/custom/1.0/path/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}':
            put:
              parameters:
                - in: path
                  name: param1
                  type: string
                  required: true
                - in: path
                  name: param2
                  type: string
                  required: true
                - in: path
                  name: param3
                  type: string
                  required: true
              requestBody:
                required: true
                content:
                  application/json:
                    schema:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        name:
                          type: string
                        city:
                          type: string
                        coordinates:
                          $ref: >-
                            #/paths/~1my~1custom~11.0~1path~1%7Bparam1%7D~1%7Bparam2%7D~1%7Bparam3%7D/put/requestBody/content/application~1json/schema/properties/directions
                        directions:
                          type: object
                          properties:
                            key1:
                              type: string
                      required:
                        - name
```

Notice how the generated ref link for coordinates looks weird. It doesn't seem to use the TestObject2 but rather relies on ref link in TestObject.directions. And for directions, TestObject2 is getting substituted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it didn't have anything to do the way I defined my schema. I was using swagger-cli to bundle into one file and by default, swagger-cli creates these internal ref links. I had to add a deference  flag. This worked:

```
swagger-cli bundle apigateway/endpoints/main.api.yml --dereference --type yaml > apigateway/swagger.yml
```